# jqplot--how to have 2 lines with very different values to scale for good values in one chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

i'm using jqplot to draw charts, in one chart it will have 2 line series, but the values are quite different, one is about 2000, and the other might be more than 1,000,000,

how can i specify it to have 2 lines with 2 y axis in a way that can be displayed in one chart fine?

currently i just saw one line that's just a plain line in the bottom? my codes are something like below

```
 $.ajax({url: myurl,
     success:function(json){

        $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

         var data = eval(json);
         var ssList = data[0];

         var sdList = data[1];


         var dataOption  = [ssList];
         if(sdList.length > 0){
             dataOption[1] = sdList;
         }

         var seriesOption = {lineWidth:2, markerOptions:{style:'square'}};
        if(sdList.length > 0){
            seriesOption[1] = {renderer:$.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions:{candleStick:true}};
        }

        var axisOption ={};
        axisOption.xaxis = {
                  renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                     tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'}
                    };
        axisOption.yaxis = {autoscale:true,label: "time"};
        if(sdList.length > 0){
            axisOption.y2axis = {autoscale:true,label: "index"};
        }



         var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', dataOption, {
              title:'水木社区股票版人气指数',
              axes:axisOption,
              series:seriesOption,
             highlighter:{
                showMarker:false,
                tooltipAxes: 'xy',
                yvalues: 1,
                formatString:'<table class="jqplot-highlighter"><tr><td>日期:%s</td></tr><tr><td>人气指数:%s</td></tr></table>'    
             }

          });


    }});
```

Comment: You could use a logarithmic scale to be able to show number that are orders of magnitude apart on the same graph.

Comment: well, the way you said is someway similar to pre-process the number... while what I'm more interested in is, is there a way to have 2 y axis seperately? thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can create plots with more 'y' axes. Second example here http://www.jqplot.com/tests/zooming.php
Don't use autoscale, try to set max and min values for each one and you will have your plot more readable.